Is it possible to estimate where the coma-free zone is based on the secondary mirror reflection seen through a collimation eyepiece?
If I understand correctly, the whole point of collimation is to make the coma-free zone at the center of the image at the image plane. I would like to understand how accurate the collimation needs to be to know if collimation is good enough when looking at the telescope through a collimation eyepiece.
I have a F/5 Newtonian telescope with 2" focuser. A 2" focuser should have 46mm field stop diameter.
The coma-free zone of F/5 Newtonian can be calculated from the equation $0.022\  \mathrm{mm} \cdot 5^3 = 2.75\ \mathrm{mm}$, quite bit smaller than the entire image.
So the coma-free zone is $\frac{2.75\ \mathrm{mm}}{46\ \mathrm{mm}} = 5.9785\%$ of the whole image (measured by linear dimensions not by areal dimensions), at the center of the image if collimation is perfect.
If I look inside a Newtonian telescope through a collimation eyepiece, and see both (1) the secondary mirror reflection, less than 5.9785% away from the middle of the primary mirror, as measured by the radius of the primary mirror, and (2) all of the retaining clips of the primary mirror, can I conclude that the coma-free zone includes the center of the image formed by the telescope, and therefore the collimation is good enough even for high-power eyepieces and imaging small objects at the center of field of view with high-resolution cameras?
And similarly for a F/4 Newtonian, the coma-free zone would be 1.408 mm and the reflection of the secondary mirror could be only 3.0609% away from the middle of the primary mirror, right?
Of course the collimation could be made nearly arbitrarily good, but maintaining it at this "nearly arbitrarily good" state might require lots of time often.
